# Assembly Mips - convert two Strings (containing Float) and find the Gap between them

Tags: arrays, assembly, floating-point, int, mips

I have to create a function that returns the difference between two floats.

Example: User A's lat is 22.00, and User B's lat is 20.00 (or 24.00) the result must be 2.00.

This is a easy subtraction yeah...... I Found a way to store the floats without \n and the point but i can't find a way to use the array in an arithmetical operation. That's very frustating.

I hope somebody help me

```
.data

dot: .asciiz "."
aCapo: .asciiz "\n"

A: .word    nome1, cognome1, lat1, long1
nome1: .asciiz "Paolo\n"
cognome1: .asciiz "Bonomi\n"
lat1: .asciiz "69.31\n"
long1: .asciiz "45.00\n"

B: .word    nome2, cognome2, lat2, long2
nome2: .asciiz "Xhoni\n"
cognome2: .asciiz "Lara\n"
lat2: .asciiz "40.02\n"
long2: .asciiz "90.00\n"

array: .space 256

.text
.globl main

main:

la $a1, A
la $a2, B

la $t8, array

lw $s1, 8($a1)
lb $t0, 0($s1)
sb $t0, 0($t8)
lb $t0, 1($s1)
sb $t0, 1($t8)
lb $t0, 3($s1)
sb $t0, 2($t8)
lb $t0, 4($s1) 
sb $t0, 3($t8)
```

EDIT: i just find a way to do this

this function works great, btw i know is not functional at all.. there is so much redundancy but i dont have so much time so.. thanks so much for the tips and help

diff_geo:

```
array: .word 1
array2: .word 1

risultatoLat: .word 1
empty: .word 1

risultatoLong: .word 1
empty2: .word 1

#
# this fuction takes two utentiR in $a1 and $a2
# and return the difference by  lat and long from the two user
#

try_lat:
lw $s1, 8($a1)  # put in s1 adress lat1
la $t8, array

lb $t0, 4($s1) #
sb $t0, 0($t8) # 
lb $t0, 3($s1) # 
sb $t0, 1($t8) # 
lb $t0, 1($s1) # 
sb $t0, 2($t8) # 
lb $t0, 0($s1) # 
sb $t0, 3($t8) # 
lw $s0, 0($t8) # put in s0 lat1 without "." and "\n"

lw $s2, 8($a2) # put in s2 address lat2 
la $t9, array2 #

lb $t0, 4($s2) #
sb $t0, 0($t9) # 
lb $t0, 3($s2) # 
sb $t0, 1($t9) # 
lb $t0, 1($s2) # 
sb $t0, 2($t9) # 
lb $t0, 0($s2) # 
sb $t0, 3($t9) # 
lw $s1, 0($t9)  # put in s1 lat2 without "." and "\n" 

blt $s0, $s1, switch_utenti     # if latA < latB goto switch
beq $s0, $s1, return_equal      # if latA = latB return "00.00"

j do_sub_lat    # else do sub 

return_equal:
la $a0, str_diffLat # stamp "Differenza Latitudine: "
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, str_same # stamp "00.00\n"
li $v0, 4
syscall

j try_long # goto process long

switch_utenti:
move $a0, $a1
move $a1, $a2
move $a2, $a0

do_sub_lat:
lw $s1, 8($a1)          # put in s1 adress lat1
lw $s2, 8($a2)          # put in s2 adress lat2
lb $t0, 0($s1)          # load first number of lat1
lb $t1, 0($s2)          # load first number of lat2
sub $t2, $t0, $t1       # t2 = t0 - t1 (decimal)
lb $t0, 1($s1)          # load second number lat1
lb $t1, 1($s2)          # load second number lat2
bge $t0, $t1, jEDLat    # if (T0 >= T1) jump exception 
li $t7, 1               # load 1 in t7
li $t6, 9               # load 9 in t6
sub $t2, $t2, $t7       # sub 1 from first number of the result  
add $t0, $t0, $t6       # add 9 to t0
sub $t1, $t1, $t7       # sub 1 to t1 (i have to made this because if i try to ad 10 to t0, 10 will be like "a" no "10")        
jEDLat:
sub $t3, $t0, $t1       # T0 - T1 risultato DECIMALE in T3
lb $t0, 3($s1)          # carico secondo numero di A
lb $t1, 3($s2)          # carico secondo numero di B
bge $t0, $t1, jETLat    # if (T0 >= T1) salta eccezione 
li $t7, 1               # carico 1 in T7
li $t6, 9               # carico 10 in T6
sub $t3, $t3, $t7       
add $t0, $t0, $t6
sub $t1, $t1, $t7   
jETLat: 
sub $t4, $t0, $t1       # T0 - T1 risultato DECIMALE in T4
lb $t0, 4($s1)          # carico quarto numero di A
lb $t1, 4($s2)          # carico quarto numero di B 
bge $t0, $t1, jEQLat    # if (T0 >= T1) salta eccezione 
li $t7, 1               # carico 1 in T7
li $t6, 9               # carico 10 in T6
sub $t4, $t2, $t7       
add $t0, $t0, $t6       
sub $t1, $t1, $t7 
jEQLat:
sub $t5, $t0, $t1       # T0 -T1 risultato DECIMALE in T5

addi $t2, $t2, 48
addi $t3, $t3, 48
addi $t4, $t4, 48
addi $t5, $t5, 48


la $t8, risultatoLat
la $t7, aCapo
lb $t7, 0($t7)
sb $t7, 5($t8)
sb $t5, 4($t8)
sb $t4, 3($t8)
la $t7, dot
lb $t7, 0($t7)
sb $t7, 2($t8)
sb $t3, 1($t8)
sb $t2, 0($t8)


la $a0, str_diffLat
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, risultatoLat
li $v0, 4
syscall

try_long:
lw $s1, 12($a1) # Metto in S1 la parola puntata da A1
la $t8, array

lb $t0, 4($s1) #
sb $t0, 0($t8) # 
lb $t0, 3($s1) # 
sb $t0, 1($t8) # 
lb $t0, 1($s1) # 
sb $t0, 2($t8) # 
lb $t0, 0($s1) # 
sb $t0, 3($t8) # 
lw $s0, 0($t8)  # IN S0 LONGITUDINE A

lw $s2, 12($a2) # Metto in S2 la parola puntata da A2 
la $t9, array2

lb $t0, 4($s2) #
sb $t0, 0($t9) # 
lb $t0, 3($s2) # 
sb $t0, 1($t9) # 
lb $t0, 1($s2) # 
sb $t0, 2($t9) # 
lb $t0, 0($s2) # 
sb $t0, 3($t9) # 
lw $s1, 0($t9)  # IN S1 LONGITUDINE B 

blt $s0, $s1, switch_utenti2    # se latA < latB inverto
beq $s0, $s1, return_equal2     # se latA = a latB ritorno 00.00    

j do_sub_long

return_equal2:
la $a0, str_diffLong # stampo "Differenza Longitudine: "
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, str_same # stampo "00.00\n"
li $v0, 4
syscall

jr $ra # fine funzione

switch_utenti2:
move $a0, $a1
move $a1, $a2
move $a2, $a0

do_sub_long:
lw $s1, 12($a1)         # Metto in S1 la parola puntata da A1
lw $s2, 12($a2)         # Metto in S2 la parola puntata da A2 
lb $t0, 0($s1)          # carico primo numero di A
lb $t1, 0($s2)          # carico primo numero di B
sub $t2, $t0, $t1       # T0 - T2 risultato DECIMALE in T2
lb $t0, 1($s1)          # carico secondo numero di A
lb $t1, 1($s2)          # carico secondo numero di B
bge $t0, $t1, jEDLong   # if (T0 >= T1) salta eccezione 
li $t7, 1               # carico 1 in T7
li $t6, 9               # carico 10 in T6
sub $t2, $t2, $t7        
add $t0, $t0, $t6
sub $t1, $t1, $t7       
jEDLong:
sub $t3, $t0, $t1       # T0 - T1 risultato DECIMALE in T3
lb $t0, 3($s1)          # carico secondo numero di A
lb $t1, 3($s2)          # carico secondo numero di B
bge $t0, $t1, jETLong   # if (T0 >= T1) salta eccezione 
li $t7, 1               # carico 1 in T7
li $t6, 9               # carico 10 in T6
sub $t3, $t3, $t7       
add $t0, $t0, $t6
sub $t1, $t1, $t7   
jETLong:    
sub $t4, $t0, $t1       # T0 - T1 risultato DECIMALE in T4
lb $t0, 4($s1)          # carico quarto numero di A
lb $t1, 4($s2)          # carico quarto numero di B 
bge $t0, $t1, jEQLong   # if (T0 >= T1) salta eccezione 
li $t7, 1               # carico 1 in T7
li $t6, 9               # carico 10 in T6
sub $t4, $t2, $t7       
add $t0, $t0, $t6       
sub $t1, $t1, $t7 
jEQLong:
sub $t5, $t0, $t1       # T0 -T1 risultato DECIMALE in T5

addi $t2, $t2, 48
addi $t3, $t3, 48
addi $t4, $t4, 48
addi $t5, $t5, 48

la $t7, aCapo
lb $t7, 0($t7)
la $t8, risultatoLong
sb $t7, 5($t8)
sb $t5, 4($t8)
sb $t4, 3($t8)
la $t7, dot
lb $t7, 0($t7)
sb $t7, 2($t8)
sb $t3, 1($t8)
sb $t2, 0($t8)


la $a0, str_diffLong
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, risultatoLong
li $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, aCapo
li $v0, 4
syscall

jr $ra
```

i have omitted that lat and long format is the same for all

ctrl_geo:

```
#
# questa funzione prende come argomento in $a0 una indirizzo ad una stringa
# la funzione contolla se il formato è corretto cioè rispetta il formato "xx.xx\n" con x compreso tra 0 e 9
# restituisce in $a0 1 se l'inserimento è avvenuto correttamente altrimenti stampa a video una stringa di errore
# e restituisce in $a0 0
#

lb $t0, 0($a0) # carico numero decine in $t0
lb $t1, min
blt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è minore di 0
lb $t1, max
bgt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è maggiore di 9

lb $t0, 1($a0) # carico numero unità in $t0
lb $t1, min
blt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è minore di 0
lb $t1, max
bgt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è maggiore di 9

lb $t0, 2($a0) # carico punto in $t0
lb $t1, dot
bne $t0, $t1, errore_geo # se non c'è un punto in t0 mando ad errore

lb $t0, 3($a0) # carico numero dopo punto decine in $t0
lb $t1, min
blt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è minore di 0
lb $t1, max
bgt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è maggiore di 9

lb $t0, 4($a0) # carico numero dopo punto unità in $t0
lb $t1, min
blt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è minore di 0
lb $t1, max
bgt $t0, $t1, errore_geo # controllo se è maggiore di 9

lb $t0, 5($a0) # a capo in $t0
lb $t1, aCapo
bne $t0, $t1, errore_geo # se in t0 non ho aCAPO mando a errore 

li $a0, 1
jr $ra # fine funzione

errore_geo:
la $a0, str_erroreNumerico
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $a0, 0
jr $ra # fine funzione
```

this is so unfunctional i know that... maybe if i store lat and long values like float and not like ascii that would prevented a great deal of trouble.

Comment: Good Luck finding someone who actually will take the time to write this for you. What you are asking is a lot in Assembly! I no longer remember the language very well or I would try.

Comment: Do you have to store the lat and long values as ascii? This would be much easier if you could store them as floats.

Comment: @Tim if he doesn't have string-to-float conversion, it may be easier to subtract them as strings... :D ... or to convert them into integers, if he knows there will be always only 2 decimal places, he can use 100* integers for everything, and just output it with `'.'` ahead of last two digits. (I sort of don't have idea, where I would start with writing ascii -> float convertor, probably by using C++ for it, that's one piece of treacherous code).

Comment: @Ped7g String-to-float conversion is fairly straightforward, especially since the strings are in a known format `AB.CD`. The floating point value is just `(A*10) + B + (C/10) + (D/100)`. But you are right, it may be easier to work with 100x integers, or by multiplying the strings directly. It all depends on what format the output should be, which we don't know.

Comment: @Tim for fixed format it's .. maybe straightforward.. but already by /10 and /100 you are introducing rounding, I'm not sure what's the proper strategy to accumulate the smallest possible error. But full floating point string parsing including science notation and correct handling of overflow/underflow ... it's not like I would be unable to write it, but I think it would easily eat a couple of days to have it bug free and feels really tedious. Plus there's no reason for *me* to write it, I will happily use clib version. :)

Comment: @Ped7g and Tim: Fast and *accurate* `strtod()` is a very hard problem with a lot of corner cases.  [This article](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/) describes in detail the algorithm used by glibc.  It also has a link to a similar description of the other widely used implementation (by David Gay): [How strtod() Works (and Sometimes Doesn’t)](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/).  Interesting reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean:

> can't find a way to use the array in an arithmetical operation

As in Assembly there's not even a well defined thing like "array", but you probably mean some amount of consecutive bytes.

Arithmetic instructions like `sub` can work only over registers (and only with word size).

So if you have two ASCII "numbers" in strings with removed decimal dot and newline, like:

```
num1: .byte '1', '2', '7', '8', 0  # was "12.78\n"
num2: .byte '5', '6', '3', '4', 0  # was "56.34\n"
res:  .space 16  # should be plenty for lat/lon difference
```

Get indices of last digit for both `n1i = 3, n2i = 3` and set `resi = max(n1i, n2i)`.

Now as you want absolute value of sub, you can check which number is smaller and subtract that one from the greater one.

```
num1bigger = (n2i < n1i) || (n1i == n2i && first_different_digit_is_bigger_in_n1);
// equal numbers will produce "false"
```

---

**EDIT**: actually this would produce **wrong result** for one special case: `num1 = "0012"` vs `num2 = "345"` would produce `num1bigger = true;`, the described thing works only when leading zeroes are not part of considered ASCII numbers.

This nicely (in unplanned way) illustrates why you should unit-test your algorithms with as many corner cases as you can figure out (including things like empty data and null data, when applicable), and how even "trivial" tasks can be coded with bugs easily. Well, not just coded, but already *designed* with bug on the high level.

---

Now subtraction algorithm (in C-like pseudo language, if you don't know C, then sorry):

```
    init:
      already set: n1i, n2i, num1bigger, num1, num2, res, resi
      borrow = false, res[resi+1] = 0

    sub_loop:
  *1  r1 = (0 <= n1i) ? num1[n1i--] : '0'
      r2 = (0 <= n2i) ? num1[n2i--] : '0'
      if (!num1bigger) swap(r1,r2)
      // r1 is byte-part of bigger number, r2 of smaller
      if (borrow) ++r2
  *2  r3 = r1 - r2       // ASCII - ASCII = numeric value
      borrow = (r3 < 0)
      if (borrow) r3 += 10  // adjust negative into 0-9
      r3 += '0'          // add ASCII encoding back
  *3  res[resi--] = r3
      if (0 <= resi) jump sub_loop
      // as the smaller number is subtracted from larger, borrow=0 at end
      // so no need to patch the result in sign flip way

      // but you may want to remove leading zeroes
      // (but keep at least three of them for "0.00" result)
```

This is per-byte ASCII absolute value subtraction algorithm. (both inputs [22, 20] and [22, 24] will produce +02 result!).

BTW, for non absolute subtraction it's actually almost the same, but when `!num1bigger`, the minus sign has to be added ahead of result => `22-24 = -02` (now the leading zero looks quite bad :) ).

For my example array the value inside loop will be like:

```
init:
num1bigger = false, borrow = false, res[4] = 0
  Loop first iteration:
  *1 fetching, swapping, borrow adjust: r1 = '4', r2 = '8'
  *2 subtraction, adjustment: r3 = '6', borrow = true
  *3 store result: res[3] = '6', n1i == n2i == resi == 2
  (0 <= resi (2)) -> loop again
  *1 fetching, swapping, borrow adjust: r1 = '3', r2 = '8'
  *2 subtraction, adjustment: r3 = '5', borrow = true
  *3 store result: res[2] = '5', n1i == n2i == resi == 1
  (0 <= resi (1)) -> loop again
  *1 fetching, swapping, borrow adjust: r1 = '6', r2 = '3'
  *2 subtraction, adjustment: r3 = '3', borrow = false
  *3 store result: res[1] = '3', n1i == n2i == resi == 0
  (0 <= resi (0)) -> loop again
  *1 fetching, swapping, borrow adjust: r1 = '5', r2 = '1'
  *2 subtraction, adjustment: r3 = '4', borrow = false
  *3 store result: res[0] = '4', n1i == n2i == resi == -1
  !(0 <= resi (-1)) -> exit loop
  // here res bytes are set to '4', '3', '5', '6', 0
  // which can be formatted as result 43.56 (== 56.34 - 12.78)
```

... I'm not going to try to write it in MIPS assembly, as I never did coding in it, plus I can't steal all the fun from you. I hope this above gives you idea, how you can do arithmetic operations upon ASCIIZ strings of digits.

Basically you should write it on paper, and focus what you would do when you can manipulate single digit only per step. And write that down as an algorithm.

Try it on few values (make sure there are some corner cases, like my "first_different_digit_is_bigger_in_n1", or two equal values, or `123.45 - 7.89`, `0.00` input and maybe even empty string).

And if it looks solid, just write the instructions between those steps (I tried to break my algorithm into so many simple tiny steps, that most of them should be resolved by 1-2 instructions at most, maybe sometimes 3-4 when I missed the MIPS architecture too much. I'm used to x86 instructions, so I tried to follow more RISC-like logic (avoiding flags usage for example), but still...).

Comment: Also this should be easy to extend to handle the dot `'.'` character (it should be encountered in both `num1/num2` at the same time, and just copied into `res`, skip subtraction and continue with loop). May be easier than removing it from input. The same goes for `'\n'`, you can probably keep them there, just do jump on next loop iteration when `\n` is loaded. Or even copy it to result, if desired.